# php log-parser outputs error with undefined function

Tags: php, parsing, logging

I am trying to get a log-parser working  https://github.com/kassner/log-parser  and on first trial I get an errors ->

code:

```
<?php

$parser = new \Kassner\LogParser\LogParser.php();

$lines = file('/var/log/apache24/error.log', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $entry = $parser->parse($line);
}
echo $entry;
?>
```

error output:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function php() in /usr/home/www/parselog.php on line 3
```

how do I get the logparser class to output correctly?

Comment: The OP said in a comment *quotes don't help. I have already gave up of the junk and deleted it. Trying python now.*. So this question can be closed since the user gave up.

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully the documentation you linked in your question, you will see that the class is loaded from its namespace, you should not use the `.php` extension when loading the `LogParser` class. So, you have to remove `.php` from the third line:

```
$parser = new \Kassner\LogParser\LogParser();
```

See [PHP documentation about importing namespaces](http://php.net/manual/language.namespaces.importing.php).

---

It worked for me. I installed the dependency with Composer:

```
composer require kassner/log-parser:~1.0
```

And used your code in a <kbd>log.php</kbd> file:

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$parser = new \Kassner\LogParser\LogParser();

$lines = file('/var/log/apache2/access.log', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $entry = $parser->parse($line);
}
echo $entry;
```

Then I executed it:

```
php -f log.php
```

It throws an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Kassner\LogParser\FormatException' with message '127.0.0.1 - - [01/Apr/2015:00:32:01 +0200] "GET /... HTTP/1.1" 200 1753 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 ... Firefox/35.0"' in /.../vendor/kassner/log-parser/src/Kassner/LogParser/LogParser.php:73

The error is about the format of my <kbd>access.log</kbd> file, but the `LogParser` class was successfully loaded.

Comment: same issue if the .php is dropped  ->  Fatal error: Class 'Kassner\LogParser\LogParser' not found in /usr/home/www/logparser/src/parselog.php on line 3 and if I try it with autoload I get ->  https://bpaste.net/show/590385584abf

Comment: The error says `Use of undefined constant vendor`, you have to add some quotes before and after `vendor/autoload.php`.

Comment: quotes don't help. I have already gave up of the junk and deleted it. Trying python now.